# Alternative to grouping when using subqueries (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, charts, grouping

I'm trying to create a relatively complex MySQL query to generate a stacked bar chart - count of requests by month, by department.

The approach I've been trying to use is via sub-query -- but it seems to be a dead end since the grouping by month doesn't apply in the subquery.  It repeats the same total count for each row returned, e.g.

```
MONTH     HR    ACCT  CUST SVC
October   5     1     5
November  5     1     5
December  5     1     5
```

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
MONTH(request.submissiondate), YEAR(request.submissiondate),
(SELECT count(*) from request where request.DEPARTMENTID='1') as 'Human Resources',
(SELECT count(*) from request where request.DEPARTMENTID='2') as 'Accounting',
(SELECT count(*) from request where request.DEPARTMENTID='3') as 'Customer Service'

FROM request 
WHERE YEAR(request.submissiondate) = 2011
group by MONTH(request.submissiondate), YEAR(request.submissiondate)
```

Hoping there's a relatively simple alternative approach that I'm just missing.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
SELECT 
MONTH(request.submissiondate), YEAR(request.submissiondate), request.DEPARTMENTID, COUNT(*) as 'total'
FROM request 
WHERE YEAR(request.submissiondate) = 2011
group by MONTH(request.submissiondate), YEAR(request.submissiondate), request.DEPARTMENTID
ORDER BY request.submissiondate
```

I don't know if it's possible to get exactly the output as you listed above, but you should be able to loop through the returned rows and rearrange the output with whatever server-side lamguage you are using.

Comment: I edited my answer with a different approach, let me know if this one is any better.

Comment: Brian -- actually this works well -- I think I was trying to be a bit too clever by building it all into the SQL query, but it won't take much code to use this output in my application instead.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! It's often confusing for me to decide weather or not to code something in a mysql query, or just process the results afterwards. I'm also not often sure which way is faster.